# Lambda that decays to pointer and noexcept specification

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2017, function-pointers, noexcept

Consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    void(*ptr)() noexcept = []() noexcept {
        // ...
    };
}
```

It compiles with gcc/clang but it fails to compile with msvc.
The error is quite obscure:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'main::' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void) noexcept'
>   note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Everything works fine if I remove the `noexcept` as it follows:

```
int main() {
    void(*ptr)() = []() noexcept {
        // ...
    };
}
```

As far as I can see, the code is correct and msvc should accept it as well as gcc and clang. Is there something wrong in the snippet or is it a bug of msvc?

Comment: Looks like it is/was a bug. Cannot reproduce with MSVS 15.8.0 and compiler version 19.15.26726.

Comment: @NathanOliver I can reproduce it with vs2017. :-(

Comment: Which version of the IDE and compiler?

Comment: @NathanOliver I reproduced it both on appveyor and on godbolt, both with vs2015 and vs2017. I don't remember what versions they use exactly and I'm not at my laptop right now. I can check it later.

Comment: Godbolt uses 19.10.25017 which was released in march 2017 so it is probably a bug/lack of functionality that has since been fixed/added.

Comment: @NathanOliver So, the same probably applies to appveyor when using vs2017, right?